# Dynamically create routes array for Angular Router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I'd like to create the `routes` array for the Angular router dynamically to conditionally include lazy loaded routes.

**app-routing.ts**

```
// fix declaration working perfectly fine - nothing special here
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'some-url', loadChildren: './path/to/my.module#MyLazyLoadedModlue'},
      ...
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

---

To achieve the conditional use of the lazy loaded route I tried:

```
const useModule = true;  // simulating condition here

children: [
  useModule ? { path: 'some-url', loadChildren: './path/to/my.module#MyLazyLoadedModlue' } : [],
  ...
]
```

As this technique works perfectly fine for conditionally including modules, I thought it would work, but it resulted in a TS error I couldn't get around.

> Type '{ path: string; loadChildren: () => typeof MyLazyLoadedModlue; } | undefined[]' is not an array type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.

---

Next I tried to generate the routes with a function...

```
function getRoutes() {
  // some logic to dynamically generate the routes array

  return routes;
}

imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(getRoutes())],
...
```

... which causes a compile error:

> ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined

Does anyone know how this could be achieved and explain why this causes trouble? I thought it won't be a problem do generate the routes array dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand a reason for conditional if a route is loaded dynamically, mind explaining?

Comment: I use different environments to support different builds. In some builds the complete functionality of a lazy loaded route should be cut of, therefore I wanted to dynamically include the routes according to the conditions set in the respective environment file.
Maybe I'm on the complete wrong track, but I thought this should have been the easiest way to achive this with dynamic routes.

Comment: I would suggest rethinking this. Application build should be environment agnostic.

Comment: Maybe another way around would be to inject these environment files as a JSON asset during release and use them instead of env file. This really isn't that different from your original code but moves environment information to release definition.

Comment: The goal I wanted to achive by excluding the routes, is that the lazy loaded module and all its sub modules could be tree shaken away. By only using a static JSON that I use after my release buiild, I would always have the whole applicaton in my build, even if some parts won't ever be used.

Comment: True, this would be a disadvantage for your case. Can't come up with a better idea :/

Comment: Nonetheless thank you, I'm grateful for every thought that could lead me in the right way or towards a new idea.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you're declaring a nested children array on false state:

```
children : [ [] ]
```

What I think you need, at least, it's a declaration of this nested array

```
[{path: ''}]
```

try it!

Comment: Yeah I also thought this might be a problem and tried `...(useModule ?  { ... } : [])` which should work, because the spread operator does nothing if its operand is an empty Array.

Comment: Your solution causes also an 'Error: Invalid configuration of route '': Array cannot be specified'.
Thanks anyway.